# Is there any alternate way to create a model in CV Studio?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning, image-classification

I am working on Image Classification Model in CV Studio. I am facing a big problem that whatever model I create, it shows "Model Unavailable" at the end.
Someone please help me

I tried recreating model twice but same results

[image]